# SWIG: Use different names for same template (stl vector)

Tags: c#, c++, stl, swig

we are using SWIG to create wrapper classes for C# and Python for an application interface.

The interface uses several typedefs for STL containers, some of them for the same specialization.

When running SWIG, in the generated C# file, wrapper functions always return an instance of the the first defined template that matches the argument list. The generated C++ wrapper module uses the correct typedefs, though.

The following snippet is a very simplified .i file that illustrates the problem:

```
%module swig

%include "std_vector.i"
%template(WrappedVectorOfInts) std::vector<int>;
%template(WrappedIntVector) std::vector<int>;
%template(WrappedAnotherIntVector) std::vector<int>;

typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
typedef std::vector<int> AnotherIntVector;

std::vector<int> GetVectorOfInts();
IntVector GetIntVector();
AnotherIntVector GetAnotherIntVector();
```

This results in the follwing CSharp class:

```
public class swig {
  public static WrappedVectorOfInts GetVectorOfInts() {
    WrappedVectorOfInts ret = new WrappedVectorOfInts(swigPINVOKE.GetVectorOfInts(), true);
    return ret;
  }

  public static WrappedVectorOfInts GetIntVector() {
    WrappedVectorOfInts ret = new WrappedVectorOfInts(swigPINVOKE.GetIntVector(), true);
    return ret;
  }

  public static WrappedVectorOfInts GetAnotherIntVector() {
    WrappedVectorOfInts ret = new WrappedVectorOfInts(swigPINVOKE.GetAnotherIntVector(), true);
    return ret;
  }

}
```

The generated CXX file contains the correctly typed wrapper methods:

```
SWIGEXPORT void * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_GetVectorOfInts() {
  void * jresult ;
  std::vector< int > result;

  result = GetVectorOfInts();
  jresult = new std::vector< int >((const std::vector< int > &)result); 
  return jresult;
}


SWIGEXPORT void * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_GetIntVector() {
  void * jresult ;
  IntVector result;

  result = GetIntVector();
  jresult = new IntVector((const IntVector &)result); 
  return jresult;
}


SWIGEXPORT void * SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_GetAnotherIntVector() {
  void * jresult ;
  AnotherIntVector result;

  result = GetAnotherIntVector();
  jresult = new AnotherIntVector((const AnotherIntVector &)result); 
  return jresult;
}
```

I've tried with %clear and %apply already, but I always seem to make a mistake, because I never get the desired effect.

Is there a way to force SWIG to use the correct typenames in the generated C# interface?

We are currently using SWIG-3.0.2 on Windows.

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt you can do this with SWIG. In fact, the SWIG documentation states that wrapping the same template instantiation more than once in the same scope produces an error. I guess in later SWIG versions, consequent template instantiations of the same template are ignored, since no errors are raised.